# Cannot set cookie name with underscore in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I cannot set cookies having an underscore in the cookie name with my chrome extension.
[image]
Here is the relevant code where i set the cookie

```
if (Number(request.expirationDate) == 0) {
                    chrome.cookies.set({url:request.url ,name: request.name ,value: request.value , domain: request.domain , path: request.path , secure: asBoolean(request.secure) , httpOnly: request.httpOnly}); 
                    } else {
                    chrome.cookies.set({url:request.url ,name: request.name ,value: request.value , domain: request.domain , path: request.path , secure: asBoolean(request.secure) , httpOnly: request.httpOnly  , expirationDate: Number(request.expirationDate)});
                    }
```

**Edit**
After closer inspection i found out that the value is empty for that cookie.This is what i am sending to the chrome extension.

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(editorExtensionId, {"url":"https:\/\/my.test.com","name":"wordpress_user_sw_1ef0e9e7d0d89edf025ec2f501da879c","value":" ","domain":"my.test.com","path":"\/","secure":"FALSE","httpOnly":false,"expirationDate":"1552372713"});
```

Comment: Why do you think the problem is an underscore? Did you try stripping underscores and it succeeded? I think it's more likely you have an invalid number like `NaN` in Number(request.expirationDate) or some other invalid parameter.

Comment: @wOxxOm you might be right , check my edit

Comment: Removing black space from the value parameter in case its empty seems to have fixed the error.However white space are allowed in cookie spec so i don't know what was wrong